# How to exctract data from JSON with scrapy?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract the validity data from a JSON, but it is at another level and I have not been able to access the data, I tried  but it does not work, this is the base code before testing.

```py
import scrapy
import json
 
API_URL = "https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/promociones.json?per_page=9999&tags=home&custom_fields=true&order_by=updated_at&desc=true&hash=721"

class BanSantanderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bansantander"
    start_urls = [API_URL]
 
    # Custom Settings are needed to send the User Agent.         
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
 
    def parse(self, response):
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        datas = json_response["promociones"]
        for data in datas:
            yield {
                "title": data["title"],
                "description": data["description"],
                "summary": data["slug"],
                "discount": data["excerpt"],
                "discountURL": data["url"]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `response.json()` convenience function to convert the response to a json object which you can then iterate through to extract the data you need. See sample usage below. I have added the use of `Item`s to clean up the outputted data.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst

@dataclass
class BanSantanderItem:
    title: Optional[str] = field(default=None)
    description: Optional[str] = field(default=None)
    summary: Optional[str] = field(default=None)
    discount: Optional[str] = field(default=None)
    discountURL: Optional[str] = field(default=None)


class BanSantanderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bansantander'
    allowed_domains = ['banco.santander.cl']
    start_urls = ['https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/promociones.json?per_page=9999&tags=home&custom_fields=true&order_by=updated_at&desc=true&hash=721']

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for entry in response.json().get('promociones'):
            loader = ItemLoader(item=BanSantanderItem(), selector=entry)
            loader.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
            loader.add_value("title", entry.get('title'))
            loader.add_value("description", entry.get("description"))
            loader.add_value("summary", entry.get("slug"))
            loader.add_value("discount", entry.get("discount"))
            loader.add_value("discountURL", entry.get("url"))

            yield loader.load_item()
```